# Whats the difference between those two Samsung 4GB 2Rx8 PC3 - 10600S memories

Tags: memory

Can someone expalain to me what is the difference between those two ram memories Samsung 4GB 2Rx8 PC3 - 10600S - 09 - 11 - F3 vs Samsung 4GB 2Rx8 PC3 - 10600S - 09 - 11 - F2 , i guess that those two are compatible but i was woundering what do all those numbers mean I couldnt find explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are timings interpretation of modules.

CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-CMD.

CL: CAS Latency. The time it takes between a command having been sent to the memory and when it begins to reply to it. It is the time it takes between the processor asking for some data from the memory and it returning it.

tRCD: RAS to CAS Delay. The time it takes between the activation of the line (RAS) and the column (CAS) where the data are stored in the matrix.

tRP: RAS Precharge. The time it takes between disabling the access to a line of data and the begin of the access the another line of data.

tRAS: Active to Precharge Delay. How long the memory has to wait until the next access to the memory can be initiated.

All that you need to watch out for is the 'CL' Both are 09.

In general, the lesser the CL, the better the performance.

Comment: If I understood well, those two are compatatible, but I guess they wont run in dual channel?

Comment: They might run in Dual Channel. Its a small difference, but then Delay timings may end up as conflict for identical Dual Channel.